# ART option in Developer mode Cause a Issue

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

In my android phone i have a problem,i just select ART option in Developer settings.Then my phone ask me to restart your phone.I just restart my phone.Then when it starts a strange problem occur.
I was not able to type my password i click on password place many times but not at all any response.Then i type on emergency call to use numbers,a message appear that keyboard has stopped working.
I also drawn out my sim card and memory card but still the same issue.
Guys what should i do now.I have no option(not any factory data reset and my phone i think not have recovery option).
My mobile is Q mobile LT250.

Comment: Also a icon of less storage is appear above,it was not before this issue.

Comment: ART on KitKat is an experimental runtime, so it's (unfortunately) understandable that it could be buggy on some devices. Note that using ART will increase space usage, that's why you have "low storage" message.

Comment: Guys is there not any one to solve this issue?

Comment: I can only suggest factory reset in this case, or at least try to access recovery option (e.g. holding vol up+vol down+power, or similar combination)

Comment: Had you USB debugging enabled before switching to ART? There might be a shell command (which could be executed via `adb shell`) to witch back to Dalvik (I vaguely remember having seen something like that).

Comment: Thank you guys for all of you comments,before your comments i try to figure it out on google.I go through sites which told to get recovery option in many ways.Some said vol, up+vol.down+power and some power+vol.up.But any of them failed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all of you comments,before your comments i try to figure it out on google.I go through different sites which told to get recovery option in many ways.Some said vol. up+vol.down+power and some power+vol.up.But any of them failed to work.Then i try different combinations then finally i got That Two Options "Recovery mode"and "Factory mode ".I applied factory mode,guys i lost my all saved data but i,m happy my phone is now working fine.That method was, switch off phone after a few seconds press and hold power button.When you feel vibration then at once press both volume buttons(Both in same time).Then that two options will appear.vol.up and vol. down for scrolling.Home and left most touch buttons are for selection and starting procedure.